# Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: adb: device offline {ERROR}

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I keep getting this error when trying to start emulator on android. I don't have a device plugged in only attempting to test to see if my new installations of android studio and emulators work, I am using a Mac with the M1 chip. Any help please.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the android studio as it may be corrupted or change the device and see

Hope this works :)

Comment: Thanks but that did not work. my emulators are offline. can't get any to come online. I tried the debugging settings on the emulators, still would not come online.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a number of different things that cause that error. Here are some troubleshooting steps to try:

- Reboot the phone
- Try a different USB cable, or unplug it and re-plug it back in
- Use command line tools to relaunch adb if it gets hung up; try `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server` and then `adb devices`
- Reset the USB debugging on the device in the settings; disable it and re-enable it
- Try changing transfer modes in the USB debugging (i.e. camera PTP)
- Close and restart Android Studio

Comment: I am only trying to launch my app in an emulator. The emulator runs but when I type in a in terminal to open my app in the emulator, it gives the error above.

Comment: @Efe O In the past, I've spent hours troubleshooting Android apps that behave strangely on an emulator. Then, when I've deleted the emulator through the AVD manager and recreated the emulator, everything magically worked. Try that and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Android studio emulators are still based on Intel Haxm virtualization software. I'm sure updates to AS are coming but for now you need to download a separate emulator to run an AVD (Android Virtual Device). It's pretty easy to download and install.

You can find it here: https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview